# ¿Cómo hacer el zoom de un ImageView con Glide?

Tags: java, android-studio, zoom

Estoy tratando de hacer zoom a una imagen pero no me funciona. Es sencillo pero no me deja lanzar la app porque me da error en `.into(mPlace)` .

**DetailActivity.java:**

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView mPlace;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    mPlace = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    //mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(mPlace);

    Bundle mBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(mBundle != null){
        //mPlace.setImageResource(mBundle.getInt("Image"));
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(mBundle.getInt("Image")).into(mPlace);
    }
}
}
```

**activity_detail.xml** :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 tools:context="com.example.imagenes.DetailActivity">

 <ImageView
 android:id="@+id/imageView"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:scaleType="centerInside" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Pongo la dependencia correcta y después introduzco esto en el XML (pero no se si tengo que quitar ImageView o dejar esto solo):

```
<com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.SubsamplingScaleImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Y sustituyendo lo que tengo en xml junto con `SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView = (SubsamplingScaleImageView)findViewById(id.imageView);` pero algo pongo mal aqui y me da error en el `.into()`

Comment: cuál es el; error?

Comment: El error es tal como digo en `into(mPlace)` que se me subraya en rojo y me dice que no puedo utilizarlo..

Comment: El problema que estoy usando PhotoView también pero como error me marca que "Manifest merger failed: Attribute application|appComponentFactory value= ...." por lo que no me soluciona tampoco nada.

Comment: Lo que pasa aquí es que estoy usando `Glide` y, o me falla el `into()` de Glide, o me funciona eso y me sale un error como el anterior comentario

Comment: A simpe vista no parece que exista algún error en tu código, es posible que el error ocurra por versiones de las librerías, ¿podrías compartir tu gradle de las dependencias?

Comment: lo habia quitado todo ya, voy a volver a ponerlo para decirte que me sale

Comment: He leido @JesúsMiraanda que con esta libreria , con davemorrissey, ya no es posible... sabes de algo para que pueda hacer zoom? He probado con **photoview** pero me aparecen problemas de Merge Manifest, Android studio provoca errores por todo... Hasta para hacer un simple zoom que en Unity tardaria 1 minuto, con esto estoy horas para una chorrada...

Comment: Yo he utilizado con éxito la librería TouchImageView (aunque yo lo implementé con picasso) https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView, aunque si las librerías te están causando problemas, quizá sea bueno no utilizarlas.Existen clases como ScaleGestureDetector que es relativamente sencilla  de usar. aqui puedes encontrar un ejemplo https://stackoverflow.com/a/52378131